# Handling the Optional which doesn't expected to be empty

Tags: java, option-type

I have the following method

```
private Invoice createInvoice(SomeParameter someParameter) {
    Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
    Optional<Customer> customer = customerRepository.findByCode(someParameter.getCustomerCode());
    invoice.Customer(resource.get());
    return this.createInvoice(...);
}
```

I am looking up the customer that will be assigned to the invoice. There is no chance that the customer code in the parameter does not exist in the DB.

In any case, I know that it's a bad practice to directly call the `get()` method on an optional, but still I don't want to check if the value is present, that looks like some boilerplate code. There are other fields like the customer which are optional.

Is there a better way to handle the optional here?

Comment: No chance at all? What if someone did `someParameter.setCustomerCode(random.nextInt(9000))`?

Comment: What is `resource`? Is this method supposed to be infinitely recursive, or is `this.createInvoice(...)` calling an overload? Is `invoice.Customer(resource.get());` supposed to be creating a `Customer` object (because if it is you're just throwing it away), or is it calling a method (in which case you should use standard Java naming conventions and name the method `customer`)?

Comment: One way to avoid `.get()` is to use `customer.map().orElseThrow()`, and then handle the exception, and maybe map to an Invoice record. Either way, you still need to get the value of the optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Invoice createInvoice(SomeParameter someParameter) {
    Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
    Optional<Customer> customer = customerRepository.findByCode(someParameter.getCustomerCode());
    //1.invoice.Customer(resource.orElse(null));
    //2.resource.ifPresent(res->invoice.Customer(res));
    //3.invoice.Customer(resource.orElseThrow(()->new Exception("xxx")));
    return this.createInvoice(...);
}
```

Whatever you want

Answer (score 5):

> There is no chance that the customer code in the parameter does not
> exist in the DB.

If you are sure that result is present in the optional object you've obtained, then instead of `get()` you should call [`orElseThrow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow()) which does the same - retrieves the value (*if present*), but contrary to `get()` it shows your intention to throw `NoSuchElementException` explicitly if optional object doesn't contains a result.

This method has an overloaded version which expects a supplier of type `Throwable` and allows providing the desired type of exception for the case of empty optional.

Comment: And if the OP wants a custom exception they can use [`Optional#orElseThrow(Supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow(java.util.function.Supplier)).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to handle optional then don't return it from the repository method, just return the `Customer` entity. You could also [annotate your repository method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.nullability.annotations) with `@Nullable` if necessary.

```
interface CustomerRepository extends Repository<Customer, Long> {

  Customer findByCode(...);                    
  // or
  @Nullable
  Customer findByCode(...);          

}
```